# How to read Android Intent.EXTRA_TEXT in unity

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-intent

How can I read the Intent.EXTRA_TEXT in Unity?

My Android Code is as follows:

```
intent.PutExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"teststring");
startActivity(intent);
```

My Unity Code is as follows:

```
string arguments = "";
AndroidJavaClass UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

AndroidJavaObject intent = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getIntent");
bool hasExtra = intent.Call<bool>("hasExtra", "arguments");

if (hasExtra) {
    AndroidJavaObject extras = intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getExtras");
    arguments = extras.Call<string>("getString", "arguments");
    Debug.Log("args: " + arguments);
}
```

And it does not work.
Also, I haven't modified the AndroidManifest.xml in Unity. Am I missing something?

I don't know much about accessing Intent data within Unity.
I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: `hasExtra` returns false everytime.

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75084566/9629222