# Read intent from Android Studio in Unity

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, android-intent

I have a Unity game exported into Android Studio. I have a list of saved games that stores each game's last scene that the player played. Basically stores the player's progression.

The writing of the last scene played from Unity to Android Studio works great. However, I don't know how to read from Android Studio in Unity. I have a putExtra intent that should pass the scene index into Unity but I don't know how. I should also probably mention that this java script is the only one I wrote, meaning I don't have other methods that are not mentioned here.

I found a code online that does that but I don't know to modify it so it would work with my Java script. I would really appreciate it if somebody could help!

**My Java script (in Android Studio):**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int lastscene = 99;
    Button btnstart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


//gets the PlayerPrefs from Unity
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName() + ".v2.playerprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Saves the last played scene (which is stores in the PlayerPrefs we got) in "lastscene"
        lastscene = sharedPreferences.getInt("Scene",99);

//The reading from Unity works! Toasts the last played scene when you open the Android Studio app
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+lastscene,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        btnstart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstart);

//Once you press the button, Unity should open and start playing from the last scene that we saved into Android Studio.
        btnstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("listScene", lastscene);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
       }
    }
```

**C# that I found online and don't know how to make it work (Unity):**

```
    private void Awake () 
    {
    getIntentData ();
}

private bool getIntentData () {
#if (!UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_ANDROID)
    return CreatePushClass (new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"));
#endif
    return false;
}

public bool CreatePushClass (AndroidJavaClass UnityPlayer) {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaObject intent = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject> ("getIntent");
    AndroidJavaObject extras = GetExtras (intent);

    if (extras != null) {
        string ex = GetProperty (extras, "listScene");
        return true;
    }
#endif
    return false;
}

private AndroidJavaObject GetExtras (AndroidJavaObject intent) {
    AndroidJavaObject extras = null;

    try {
        extras = intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject> ("getExtras");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.Log (e.Message);
    }

    return extras;
}

private string GetProperty (AndroidJavaObject extras, string name) {
    string s = string.Empty;

    try {
        s = extras.Call<string> ("getString", name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.Log (e.Message);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Credit to where I took the Unity script from: [Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098400/read-android-intent-extra-data-on-unity-app-launch/65092095#65092095)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to pass a string from Android to Unity by intent and show it into a text mesh component.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class TextBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {


[SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI textMesh; // Drag component
private string stringFromAndroid = string.Empty;

private void Awake()
{
    getIntentData();
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    textMesh.text = stringFromAndroid;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
}

private bool getIntentData()
{
    return CreatePushClass (new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"));
}


public bool CreatePushClass(AndroidJavaClass UnityPlayer)
{
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaObject intent = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getIntent");
    AndroidJavaObject extras = GetExtras(intent);

    if (extras != null)
    {
        stringFromAndroid = GetProperty(extras, "Literal"); // Use same as intent extra key
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private AndroidJavaObject GetExtras(AndroidJavaObject intent)
{
    AndroidJavaObject extras = null;

    try
    {
        extras = intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getExtras");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.Message);
    }

    return extras;
}

private string GetProperty(AndroidJavaObject extras, string name)
{
    string s = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        s = extras.Call<string>("getString", name);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.Message);
    }

    return s;
}
}
```

Here is the activity invocation

```
class UnityActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val intent = Intent(this, UnityPlayerActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("Literal", "I am a string from Android")
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

}